# Showing a simple algebraic relation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My question is simple but I'm not sure how to solve it. Given $x=a+b+c$, $y=a-b+c$, and $z=a+b-c$, is it possible to write $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Did you meant write z as a function of x and y instead ? Because at the moment z = f(a, b, c)

Comment: Yes, I typed it wrong, sorry. It's edited now.

Comment: Show us your attemt, otherwise is your question in danger of deletion.

Comment: @user376343 There's really not much progress in my attempts, unfortunately. I just played with different combinations of the variables to see if I was getting somewhere. No success. If you think this is a worthless question you might delete it. But can you please give me some hints instead?

Comment: Btw, I'm putting this question to myself. It's not homework.

Comment: I'm actually interested in the steps of finding the solution as well. I'd love the question to not be deleted.

Comment: @almagy enclose in your question what you have written in comment (some combination, even if they led nowhere). Or - give a goal - why do you want to solve this? 
No, I do not want to delete the question, that's why I am taking action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

Consider

$$a=b=c=0\to x=y=z=0$$ and

$$a=1,b=0,c=-1\to x=y=0,z=2.$$

For the same $(x,y)$, you can have different $z$.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is equivalent to:

*Are the vectors $x=(1,1,1), y=(1,-1,1), z=(1,1,-1)$ linearly dependent?*

The answer is negative, as the matrix $$\left[\begin{array} &1&\;\;\,1&\;\;\,1\\1&-1&\;\;\,1\\1&\;\;\,1&-1\end{array}\right]$$ is invertible.

Comment: Is this also valid for non-linear combinations of variables?